# How do I get a list of tables that have not been updated within a certain date range?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, audit

I use Alteryx to push data into our SQL Server and then I use SSMS to view the tables. I have over 100 tables and currently, I go through each table and do a `select top 1000 rows` to see the `SysUpdatedOn` column which is a date stamp to validate that my table has been updated. Is there a query that will go through every table and look for a time stamp that is prior to a specific date and give me a list of those tables? I'm looking to get a list of tables that were not updated during our data refresh process.

I found this query and it will look for a specific string in all tables, however, I am unable to add something like this to the below query.

```
DECLARE @SearchStr NVARCHAR(100) <= 11/6/2018

USE DATABASE_NAME

DECLARE @SearchStr NVARCHAR(100) = 'SEARCH_TEXT'
DECLARE @Results TABLE (ColumnName NVARCHAR(370), ColumnValue NVARCHAR(3630))

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(256), 
        @ColumnName NVARCHAR(128), 
        @SearchStr2 NVARCHAR(110)

SET  @TableName = ''
SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @ColumnName = ''
    SET @TableName = 
    (
        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
          AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
          AND OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + 
                                       QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)), 'IsMSShipped') = 0
    )

    WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName =
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
              AND TABLE_NAME = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
              AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar', 'int', 'decimal')
              AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
        )

        IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @Results
            EXEC
            (
                'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + 
@ColumnName + ', 3630) 
                FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
            )
        END
    END    
END

SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM @Results
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you know the column exists in every table, you can just loop through every table (or just those that have that column) and hard code that part of the query

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `LAST_USER_UPDATE` column in `SYS.DM_DB_INDEX_USAGE_STATS` to check for the last time data was inserted or updated.  If you need to track DDL changes, use the `MODIFY_DATE` column in `SYS.OBJECTS`, but since you're looking for changes during the refresh I'm guessing your want to track DML.  The `GETDATE`/`DATEADD` filter is just an example, you can replace this with the date you need to filter by.

```
SELECT O.NAME AS TABLENAME 
FROM SYS.OBJECTS O
INNER JOIN SYS.DM_DB_INDEX_USAGE_STATS I ON O.OBJECT_ID = I.OBJECT_ID
--FOR USER TABLES
WHERE O.TYPE = 'U' AND I.LAST_USER_UPDATE < DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: +1 One caveat, though - the `last_user_update` field will update on a blank insert/update.  So if 100 inserts are always executed in a batch, but only some have data to insert, this will still show all 100 destination tables as modified.

Answer (score 0):

Something I just discovered researching your query (that could be pretty cool and expanded on that I may start using), if you know for certain the column exists in every table in the DB, this may work, it executes on every table in the DB:
https://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2007/10/23/60383.aspx

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (TableName VARCHAR(5000), CountRows INT)

INSERT INTO @Table        
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1 = 'select ''?'', count(*) from ? WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE SysUpdatedOn >= ''11/6/2018'' '

SELECT * FROM @Table
```